# PHP on Windows Server - upgrade

Tags: php, windows, iis, upgrade

I currently have a Windows 2003 server running both IIS (for classic ASP support) and PHP version 5.2.6

I have a new server, Windows 2012R2 again running IIS, and I'm trying to figure out what to install for PHP...

Should I:

1) Install 5.6.21 or should I jump to 7.0.6 - and if I go to 7, will all my PHP code still run ok?

2) What is the difference between "Thread Safe" and "Non Thread Safe" - this seems to be an important choice when downloading the correct version, and I don't understand what the difference is....

Thanks for any information!

Comment: check out http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 7 has some [backwards incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php), so your code might not work.

For IIS, it is recommended to use Non-Thread safe as specified in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php#install.windows.iis7.fastcgi.conf).

> Note:
>   Non-thread-safe build of PHP is recommended when using IIS. The non-thread-safe builds are available at » PHP for Windows: Binaries and Sources Releases.